# Typescript Member Function returning another Function

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I have a class

```
import {Request, Response, Router} from 'express';
import {IAccessTokenMiddleWare} from "./IAccessTokenMiddleWare";

class AccessTokenMiddleWare implements IAccessTokenMiddleWare {


    private jwtToken: string;
    constructor() {

        this.jwtToken = "";
    }
    public init()  : any  {

        return function (req: Request, res: Response, next: any) {

            this.addJwtToReqBody(req);
        }
    }

    private addJwtToReqBody(req) {

        console.log("ADDED...")
    }
}

export {AccessTokenMiddleWare}
```

I am invoking it like below

```
var accessTokenMiddleWare = new AccessTokenMiddleWare();
router.use(accessTokenMiddleWare.init());
```

Getting the error

> error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not
>   have a type annotation.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions in Typescript (and JavaScript) do not have a fixed `this`, so `this` is determined by the caller. The function you return could be invoked with any `this` object, and so the compiler assumes `this` to be any by default, leading to an error if you use `strict`:

```
accessTokenMiddleWare.init().call({ newThis: true });
```

If you want to capture this from the declaring context you should use an arrow function that will type `this` as the current class:

```
class AccessTokenMiddleWare implements IAccessTokenMiddleWare {


    private jwtToken: string;
    constructor() {

        this.jwtToken = "";
    }
    public init() {

        return (req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => {

            this.addJwtToReqBody(req);
        }
    }

    private addJwtToReqBody(req: Request) {

        console.log("ADDED...")
    }
}
```

**Note** I also removed the type annotation from `init` you can let the copiler infer that the return will be a function and get better type checking. You could also specify it manually : `init(): (req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => void`